# mysql release deleted tables

Tags: mysql, linux, filesystems

In an emergency I moved a database out of my /var/lib/mysql partition because I needed space, but after I moved it the space wasn't released. I found that it was held as deleted and could view it when I viewed the output of this command.

```
lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)' | grep mysql
```

I'm running out of space and I need to recover that space from the database I moved.

What can I do?

Comment: It's a huge production db and takes about a 1/2 hour to reboot. I really want to avoid restarting the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this problem before. Create the database name and drop the database then it releases that namespace.